# addEventListener 'playing' only fires once.

Tags: javascript, html5-video, addeventlistener

I have the following `script` which gets all `video` elements on a given page and then applies a `playing` event to them:

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

for(var i = 0; i < video.length; i++){
 (function(vid) {
     vid.addEventListener('playing', function(){
       var percentComplete = Math.round((vid.currentTime / vid.duration) * 100);
       console.log(percentComplete);
     });
 })
 (video[i]);
}
```

Now when I run the page and click on video 1 for example I see the `percentComplete` being logged to the `console log`, however when video 1 finishes and I click video 2 nothing is written to the `console`, it seems this `addEventListener` is only applied to the first video that is clicked, can someone explain why and how I can resolve this so it fires every time a video is played?

Comment: You probably should give us a live demo (either StackSnippet® or fiddle) reproducing the issue, because your actual code should work ; the one by @gyre should work too *(now that s/he fixed her/his typo)*, and you could also just use `this`, but I guess no alternative solution will fix the underlying problem, which is not visible in your code block.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the outer closure and using event.target within your listener.

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

for (var i = 0; i < video.length; i++) {
    video[i].addEventListener('playing', function (event) {
        var vid = event.target
        var progress = Math.round((vid.currentTime / vid.duration) * 100)
        console.log(progress)
    })
}
```

For anyone interested, here's [the full list of media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events).

Comment: Are you trying to fire the event listener every time you click 'play'?

Comment: When I click play on video 1 for example it works, when video 1 has finished playing and I then clicked play on video 2 nothing is fired.

Comment: Haha nice catch; I meant `'playing'`